# How do i send and store values of a dynamically populated select field with Laravel framwork

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I'm working with Laravel 5.4 and I have a select field that is dynamically populated from a department's table.

EmployeeController create model

```
public function create()
{
    $departments = Department::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->get();

    return view('emp.create', compact('departments'));
}
```

Select from field dynamically populated

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="department" class="col-md-4 control-label">Department</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="dept_id"  id="dept" class="form-control" required autofocus>
         <option></option>}
         @foreach ($departments as $department)
         <option value="{{ $department->id }}">{{ ucfirst($department->name )}}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

In my employee's table, I have the dept_id column which references the department's id column. Every time I submit the form, 0 is inserted in the employees dept_id column instead of the actual value. When I `dd($request)` I can see the actual department.id being sent in the request array.

EmployeeController store model

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request);
    $employee = Employee::create(request()->all());
}
```

What's the reason the query inserts 0 everytime?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)?

Comment: There is a relationship `public function employee()
    {
     return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }` and an inverse `public function department()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Department::class);
    }`

Comment: OK, but as you've not defined a foreign key Eloquent will expect the column in the Employees table to be `department_id`, not `dept_id`

Comment: Ensure that form data has been sent with info you think is needed - you can check that in your browser's network tab. Ensure that the field `dept_id` exists and is marked as fillable in the model. You didn't provide *proper* information required to deduce why it inserts 0. There are several possibilities: 0 was selected. Field isn't fillable and default value is `0` (can't see your db, can we?). Nothing was sent via the form, so the value falls back to default one - 0. You have to inspect your code, your network traffic, perform validation etc. in order to conclude why it happens.

Comment: @Mjh thanks, the issue was not making the dept_id fillable in employees table. I forgot to do so after modifying my table structure. It works now. Cheers